# node-oracledb Error: NJS-069 in nuxt middleware

Tags: nuxt.js, node-oracledb

I can access database and get data from my Oracle db. But this error occur in my broswer console.

[image]

```
import oracledb from 'oracledb'

oracledb.outFormat = oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT

export default async function (ctx) {
  let connection

  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
      user: 'user',
      password: 'user!1',
      connectString: '127.0.0.1:1521/uat2'
    })
    const result = await connection.execute(
      `SELECT PAGETITLE, ACTIVITYID
       FROM TB_MOULD
       WHERE ACTIVITYID = 'WYDJQHD001'`,
      []
    )
    console.log(result.rows)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      try {
        await connection.close()
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I guess that webpack don't distinguish whether node-oracledb can run on non-server side during bundle process.
Anyone has solutions?

Comment: What is the node version? `node -v`

Comment: v12.18.3 @kissu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has find solution now.

```
  if (process.server) {
    const oracledb = require('oracledb')
    oracledb.outFormat = oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT
    //......
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the node-oracledb 5.0 [changelog](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md):

> Webpack users should copy the node-oracledb binary into a sub-directory of the output directory. For example if the output directory is `dist`, then the binary should be in `dist/node_modules/oracledb/build/Release/oracledb-5.0.0-linux-x64.node`. A copy plugin in `webpack.config.js` can do this by copying `node_modules/oracledb/build` to a directory of that same name. See [Issue 1156](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1156).

A potential thing to review is the use of ES modules - I have not tried them in this context.

Comment: I had tried this.it doesn't work